# Is the Openlayers "center" property buggy?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework, openlayers

I have been working on an existing codebase in react, ionic, and openlayers. Recently, I came across a task which is a crucial one. At the moment, the map always loads somewhere at (37N, 122W) around NA region something, even when in the code, there are lines which intend to recenter the map around the region of concern. I didn't know what's the issue.

On going deep into the documentations of Openlayers, I found some more functions like setCenter and adjustCenter. None of them worked. Then I set up a completely new project and the code I took was from the documentation: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/center.html

Now, as it appears on this website, when I copied the exact same code on my local device, the features in the above link didn't work in any of my devices.

I don't know how to resolve this, but if it's some bug in latest version of Openlayers, then I would like someone from the community to help me with this.

The relevant part of code:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (begin) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        const initialFeaturesLayer = new VectorLayer({
          source: new VectorSource({
            features: [],
          }),
          style: new Style({
            fill: new Fill({
              color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
            }),
          }),
        });

        const initialMap = new ol.Map({
          // set the center of the map
          target: mapElement.current,
          layers: [
            new TileLayer({
              source: new OSM({
                url: "https://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}", // Use OSM Humanitarian map style
              }),
            }),
            new VectorLayer({
              source: new VectorSource({
                features: [
                  new ol.Feature({
                    geometry: new Circle(
                      transform([-23, 0], "EPSG:4326", "EPSG:3857"),
                      50
                    ),
                  }),

                ],
              }),
            }),
          ],
          view: new ol.View({
            projection: "EPSG:3857",
            center: fromLonLat([8.16, 70.58]),
            zoom: 100,
          }),
          controls: [],
        });
        initialMap.on("click", handleMapClick);
        initialMap.addOverlay(popup);
        const size = initialMap.getSize();
        // set the center of this map to 6, 92
        initialMap.getView().setCenter(fromLonLat([8.16, 70.58]));
        // initialMap.getView().setCenter(fromLonLat([8.16, 70.58]));
        setMap(initialMap);
        setFeaturesLayer(initialFeaturesLayer);
      });
    }
    setBegin(true);
    console.log("Called");
  }, [begin]);
```

I tried changing the code, using different functions, but all went in vain. The map still reloads near NA region. The only thing where the initial map render changes is, when I set the projection to EPSG: 4326 (The default one is 3857). Nothing else had any effect on the initial map render. But I can't find any other valid EPSG codes that would render my initial map near my desired region.

Comment: 8.16, 70.58 in what EPSG format are these coordinates, did you take them from google maps?

Comment: To My knowledge the only thing other that the projections format that may be causing an In-appropriate behaviour was the fact that map was not getting the view port height width to even setup a view, but since you mentioned when you tweek the EPSG in someway you see a change in the location at which map recenter. I think that the issue you are facing is because of the coordinate system itself. Please answer my query above so i can help @Aryang22.

Comment: @JJY9, these coordinates were pre-filled in existing codebase. But as far as I know, the coordinates are of the form (8.16 N, 70.58.E), which is the concerned region.

Comment: @JJY9 I am not sure about the viewport dimensions. But yeah when I set the "projection: " to EPSG 4326, the rendered map is like a world map (zoomed out to look so, but prolly still centred around the same default region). While when the projection is set to EPSG 3857 or left blank (by default it seems to take 3857), the rendered map is quite zoomed in with centre somewhere near (37N, 122W)

Comment: Openlayer projections defaults to 'EPSG:3857', and the one's you have given are  EPSG:4326 (WGS 84) system. So you would need to convert the following, using `ol.proj.fromLonLat([70.58, 8.16])`. This is what you have indeed done. Can you share a codesandbox/stackblitz reduced testcase for this. It will help me in solving the same.

Comment: @JJY9 I apologize I am unsure of how to include all relevant code in reduced testcase format. Actually the codebase is too large including 2 backend servers. This issue as far as I think is related to UI part, that too specifically with openlayers only.

I can provide the code for this entire file (it's called MapContext.tsx). This file is used throughout the UI for making all the features in the UI functional and for global state management.